# How to free a double pointer that need to be returned from the function?

Tags: c, return, free, pointer-to-pointer

For example this is the codes for a function file, named `fnx.c`, where `func()` will be called from the main function. How should I free the `TempArray` here while return the double pointer to the main function at the same time?

```
    int * * TempArray; //global variable in this file

static void CreatePointer(int row, int col) {
    int r;
    TempArray = malloc(sizeof(int * ) * (row));
    for (r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        TempArray[r] = malloc(sizeof(int) * (col));
    }
}


static void DestroyPointer() {
    free(TempArray);
    TempArray = NULL;

}

int * * func(int * * OriArray, int row, int col, int r_offset, int c_offset) {
    int r, c;

    CreatePointer(row, col);

    for (r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < col; c++) {
            TempArray[r][c] = OriArray[r + r_offset][c + c_offset];
        }
    }

    //destroy TempArray??

    return TempArray;

}
```

Comment: the `DestroyPointer` function is incorrect. Also why would you delete a pointer after you allocate and fill the memory?

Comment: @bolov Hello there, thanks for the reply. How should I do the Destroy Pointer function then? I thought it's very direct like what I did here.
Actually I was asked by my supervisor to free every pointers after I use the malloc(), the flow is something like the one in func(), but I do not get the idea how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In your `main()`, call `CreatePointer()`
2. In your `main()`, call `func()`
3. Outside `func()`, when you don't need `TempArray` anymore, call `DestroyPointer()`

And your `DestroyPointer()` is wrong. You'll have memory leaks. It should be something like :

```
static void DestroyPointer (int row)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
    {
       free(TempArray[r]); 
    }
    free(TempArray);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Pierre , what and where do you mean by (outside main()) actually?
Sorry If I am asking stupid question.

Comment: I understand the flow now. Please ignore my previous comment (I deleted). Thanks for your answer again!

Comment: No you can't do like this, because you'll have problem if you dereference a pointer after which has been free. For now and forever, try to follow this rule : the function/class/scope which frees a pointer should be the same which has allocated it.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use this point(TempArray) after called from the main function,you can not destroy it(TempArray).Only when you do not want to use this point datas,you can destroy it.
you can test like this:

```
main()   
{   
  int *p = func(oriArray,row,col,r_offset,c_offset);   

   for (int r = 0; r < row; r++){   
       for(int c = 0; c < col; c++){   
         printf("%d",p[r][c]);   
      }   
   }      

  DestroyPointer();   
}
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

You should free all the rows before freeing up `TempArray`.

```
static void DestroyPointer (int row)
{
   for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
   {
      free(TempArray[r]);
   }
   free(TempArray);
   TempArray = NULL;

}
```

But You shouldn't destroy the pointer before returning it,
because dereferencing it after that in `main` will cause undefined behaviour.